# drf_spectacular schema annotation for optional serializer return type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have a Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer with the following SerializerMethodField:

```py
def get_segment(self, obj):
    segment = models.Segment.objects.filter(obj=obj)
    if segment.exists():
        return SegmentSerializer(segment.first()).data
```

I'm trying to use drf_spectacular's `extend_schema_field` to annotate the return type. `@extend_schema_field(SegmentSerializer)`, is close, but my function can also return `None`, so I want to do something like `@extend_schema_field(SegmentSerializer | None)`, which doesn't work. Is there a way to use a serializer type in `extend_schema_field` while marking it as nullable?

Comment: It looks a bit bizarre to return `None`/`null` if there are no segments, one would expect it to just return an empty list, by using `null`, it makes both the serializer and the tool that processes the data more complicated.

Comment: Agreed for `many=True` but I have the same issue with a singular serializer, in that case it makes more sense to return None for something that doesn't exist, otherwise you get an object with empty values and have to assume e.g. `Segment.first_name == ""` means it's `null`, having `None/null` directly seems much simpler in this case.

Comment: but here the list of segments does it exist, it is just empty. There is a difference between `[]` and `null` indeed. `null` is often used if the list of segments would be non-sensical, or is not available, that is something different than *no* segments.

Comment: Imagine that your client for example wants to iterate over the segments, then it will first have to check if it is null, whereas for an empty list, it does not need to check, it simply iterates, and will make no iterations.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've updated to remove the `many=True` since I have the same question in the single case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the [allow_null](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null) parameter, which allows a serializer to accept `None`, serializing to null:

```py
@extend_schema_field(SegmentSerializer(allow_null=True))
```